# Wrong address rertun when I call ownerof with delegatecall

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, polygon, delegatecall

I am trying to call the function "ownerof" of a contract but it return me something like that : 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000bc641d0c1acc8f85bb53aceade03bbc58de693d1

The function is :

```
    function updateRaceLeaderboard(
    uint256 raceID,
    uint256[] memory _leaderboard
) public onlyOwner returns (bytes memory addr) {
    RaceleaderBoard[raceID] = _leaderboard;
   
    address contractAddress = 0x80AFf21544b6670fCfD813134C83Bb340307c453;
    (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = contractAddress.call(
        abi.encodeWithSignature("ownerOf(uint256)", 0)
    );
    return returndata;
}
```

I call it like that:

```
    dev = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
print("Working on " + network.show_active())
trx = race.updateRaceLeaderboard(
    0,
    [0],
    {"from": dev},
)
```

The ownerOf(uint256) function is in a different contract at :

> https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x80AFf21544b6670fCfD813134C83Bb340307c453#readContract

The success bool return True

Do you know how Can I receive a correct address ?

Comment: Can you provide more details of the caller and callee contracts? How are they related? What's `ownerOf(uint256)` implementation? Did it succeed? What's `success` value returned? My suspicious is that calee throw an exception.

Comment: No it did not success :(

Comment: ownerOf(uint256) is a function of a ERC721 contract, you can saw it at : https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x80AFf21544b6670fCfD813134C83Bb340307c453#readContract

Answer (score 1):

you need to decode the return data with `abi.decode(returndata, (address))`

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you said it didn't succeed then it is not return an address but an error message

The error could be interpreted as

```
0x
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000084
08c379a0
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029
4552433732313a206f776e657220717565...
```

The `08c379a0` is a error signature `Error(string)`

Decoding the string messgae `4552433732313a206f776e657220717565` it gives

```
ERC721: owner que
```

My guess is that corresponds to

```
function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (address) {
    return _tokenOwners.get(tokenId, "ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token");
}
```

My second guess is that you shouldn't be using delegatecall, but call or staticcall instead.

---

Example how to parse the returned data

```
(bool success, bytes memory returndata) = contractAddress.call(
    abi.encodeWithSignature("ownerOf(uint256)", 0)
);


if (success) {
    (address owner) = abi.decode(returndata, (address));
    return owner;
}
```

Comment: When I use call success value is true and the returndata is : 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000bc641d0c1acc8f85bb53aceade03bbc58de693d1

It is better but why there are so many 0 before ?

Comment: @user97483 I've no idea because you haven't showed how the call and returned data is being managed. My guess is that you have to apply JiamingLi answer. If you want something to be answered please provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Ok ! I edited my post with more information about the call. Thank you for help

Comment: @user97483 Sorry, I forgot about this, I've updated the answer to include the whole code. It was as said by JiamingLi, use abi.decode to obtain the returned address.